# Let $ M = \{(a_{1}, a_{2},a_{3}) : a_{i} \in \{ 1,2,3,4\} , a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} = 6\}. $ Then what is the number of elements in $M ?$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $M = \{(a_{1}, a_{2},a_{3}) : a_{i} \in \{ 1,2,3,4\} , a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} = 6\}. $ Then what is the number of elements in $M ?$

I counted them by making different triplets and got $10$. Is there any simpler and less time consuming way to do it$?$

Comment: $(1,2,3) \Rightarrow 3!=6; (1,1,4) \Rightarrow {3\choose 1}=3;(2,2,2) \Rightarrow 1$

Answer (score 1):

A particular of the equation 
$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 6$$ 
in the positive integers corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in the five spaces between successive ones in a row of six ones.
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
For instance, if we place addition signs in the second and third spaces, we obtain
$$1 1 + 1 + 1 1 1$$
which corresponds to the solution $a_1 = 2$, $a_2 = 1$, $a_3 = 3$.  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can insert two addition signs into the five spaces between successive ones in a row of six ones, which is 
$$\binom{5}{2} = 10$$
Notice that if three positive integers have sum $6$, the largest summand is at most $4$ since $5 + 1 + 1 > 6$.  Therefore, we do not have to exclude cases in which a summand is larger than $4$, so there are $10$ solutions, as you found.

The number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n = k$$
in the positive integers is 
$$\binom{k - 1}{n - 1}$$
since we must choose $n - 1$ of the $k - 1$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $k$ ones in which to place an addition sign.

Answer (score 1):

What you are counting can be reformulated as follows:

- What is the coefficient in front of $x^6$ when expanding $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^3$? (Look at the exponents.)

Now, use the following two facts:

- $(\star):1+x+x^2+x^3 = \frac{1-x^4}{1-x}$
- $(\star\star):\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+2}{2}x^n$ (This can be easily derived by differentiating twice $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$.)

Now, you get (without any counting and further combinatorics):
\begin{eqnarray*}[x^6](x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^3
& = & [x^6]x^3(1+x+x^2+x^3)^3 \\
& \stackrel{(\star)}{=} & [x^3](1-x^4)^3\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} \\
& = & [x^3]\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} \\
& \stackrel{(\star\star)}{=} & [x^3]\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+2}{2}x^n \\
& = & \binom{3+2}{2} \\
& = & \boxed{10}
\end{eqnarray*}